# FTP connection error: INVALID COMMAND EPRT

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to get a connection to my FTP server but I can't. So, I checked what's happened on my network and I got this error message : INVALID COMMAND EPRT

What does it mean?

Comment: The least you can do is tell us what FTP server you're using, what server OS, if the firewall is active, what client FTP program you use. Has it worked before or is this a new install? And tell us what you've done to test so we don't come with suggestions for things you've already done. If you don't show that you've put some effort in it, less people will take the effort to answer!

Comment: Somehow the client thinks it's connecting to an ipv6 ftp server, but the server does not think the same